# How to connect to an on-premises SQL Server from an Azure ML notebook?

Tags: sql-server, azure, odbc, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-data-factory

I typically use pyodbc when running jupyter notebooks from my machine, but this does not work on Azure ML. My assumption is that this is being caused by Azure ML not knowing if I'm on my company's network as I typically need a VPN to the server if I'm not in office. The only solutions I can find online involve copying the data over on Azure Data Factory however I need to avoid this if possible as there are many tables I will need to experiment with, but nothing is intended to be long term and I'm unsure what I will even end up using.

Ideally there is a way to make pyodbc work but any other suggestions are welcome. I have researched integration runtimes but was unsure if that would solve my problem here.

Answer (score 0):

> The only solutions I can find online involve copying the data over on
> Azure Data Factory however I need to avoid this if possible as there
> are many tables I will need to experiment with, but nothing is
> intended to be long term and I’m unsure what I will even end up using.
> Ideally there is a way to make pyodbc work but any other suggestions

Unfortunately, the on-Prem SQL Server is not supported as a Data Source in Azure ML.
Only the Data sources available below are supported:-

[image]

***Approach1)***
You can copy your data from the on-premises SQL database to Azure SQL via copy tool in Azure Data factory and connect to Azure SQL via Azure Machine learning by directly connecting to it via Datasource like below:-

[image]

[image]

You can also use Self-hosted integration run time to connect to your SQL server on-prem in your data factory:-

[image]

[image]

Click on Option 2 to download the Integration runtime and set it in your local machine with the Registration keys mentioned above:-

[image]

***Approach2)***
If there’s a large data You can automate your entire copy process from the on-prem SQL server to Azure SQL by using the Azure DevOps pipeline.

**References:-**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/775844/unable-to-connect-sql-server-to-azure-ml-pipeline By Ramr-msft

[How To: Azure Data Factory CI/CD with Azure DevOps pipelines — The YAML WAY! | by Raghavendra Bharadwaj | Servian](https://servian.dev/how-to-azure-data-factory-ci-cd-with-azure-devops-pipelines-the-yaml-way-e035c20af275)